# Distributor ID changed to Kali

Tags: 16.04, kali

I have ubuntu 16.04 and I use this command:

```
lsb_release -a
```

and the output is:

```
Distributor ID: Kali
Description:    Kali GNU/Linux 2.0
Release:    2.0
Codename:   sana
```

How can I correct that to:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04
Release:        16.04
```

Comment: Did you install something like Kali tools?

Comment: i didn't install kali tools directly , and i'm looking which tools made this problem

Comment: It could not be changed by itself. You have Kali installed that is off-topic.

Comment: i think it effect my kernel too , at grub there is kali gnu/linux instead of ubuntu :|

Comment: What's the output of `apt-cache policy $(dpkg-query -S /etc/lsb-release | cut -d: -f1)`? That should show us where the responsible package came from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your kernel may be changed to kali , reboot your OS and see if you see ubuntu in grub or kali , if you saw kali  install new kernel from terminal and reboot , your problem will be fixed !!!!

here is tutorial to install kernel : 
[How To Install Kernel 4.4.8 On Ubuntu](http://linuxdaddy.com/blog/install-kernel-4-4-on-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 0):

You can manually modify the file `/etc/lsb-release` to revert it to the original:

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS"
```

But I think that it would be better for you to understand what's going one with your packages and which one caused the change.

Comment: it effected my kernel , at the setting -> details it is ubuntu 16.04 but at grub it shows kail gnu/linux . how i can change my kernel to ubuntu and how it changed my kernel to kali  ?

Comment: This is a different question than what you asked, but probably you installed some Kali tool. Attach to your question the output of `cat /var/log/apt/history.log /var/log/dpkg.log`.